# Why does App Engine module need an external IP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

App Engine modules exhaust Compute Engine quota called `In-use IP addresses`. I'm not able to scale App Engine modules above that quota.

Why does App Engine module need a public external IP?

Comment: Do you mean a public IP which can be accessed outside the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: @ojrask Right, I guess GCP has no quota for local area addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of Google Compute Engine.   Managed VMs use GCE under the hood to serve applications.  Currently, any virtual machine that performs outbound network calls will need to have a public external IP.  We're working on fixing that, but it's still a ways out.  By default, free trial accounts have a [default quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas) of 23 external IPs.

You can ask for a quota increase via the [quota increase request form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform), linked on the above page.